# perceptron for XOR

Tags: xor, perceptron

Perceptron is widely considered not being able to represent XOR. But how about the following network:
[image]

It seems that this network can implement XOR. Could someone help me with which part I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you've created a regressor and not a classifier - so technically not a perceptron.

Long answer: It technically works but...

```py
def generate_xor_data():
    X = np.array([
        [0,0],
        [0,1],
        [1,0],
        [1,1]])
    Y = np.array([x[0]^x[1] for x in X])
    return X, Y

def custom_activation(x):
    return x**2

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(1, input_dim=2, activation=custom_activation))
model.compile(loss="mse")

X, Y = generate_xor_data()
history = model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=1, epochs=1000)
```

[image]

And the weights learned are `[[ 0.96192336], [-1.0387915 ]]` bias is `0.04036772` which is basically what your model above was looking for.

The caveat is that the model isn't meaningful or interpretable. You wouldn't use linear regression for example to try and model arbitrary class values (like `0` and `1`) so you shouldn't do that in a neural network either (even if you can).